# TimerService stops all the time

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, timer-service

I have a new Sharepoint 2016 Farm, however i have a user the spfarmacc which runs the timerservice, this timer service is stopping suddenly, anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the System Event Log for failures of the service? Other places to look are Application and finally ULS.

Comment: its hard to find something in the ULS because we dont know exactly at what time stopped, any clue how to find info about the error?

Comment: Use the System Event Log to find out when the service stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell you the reason without information, because of there are many reasons for timer service to stop

- account ruining timer services does not have log on services and log on batch rights
- some group policy stopping it
- may be anti virus or auditing tool shutting it down.

You have to check the event logs for more clue, from event logs check application, system and setup.

Also add the timer service account into local admin on the server